# Retrieve Facebook Ad Library direct post link

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

Facebook Ad Library will show you all ads running for a particular page, but the problem is that you cannot get the ad direct post link, like this:

`https://www.facebook.com/pageID/post/postID`

It does provide the ad unique id which is useless:

[image]

How could I retrieve Facebook Ad Library direct post link?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to https://adsmanager.facebook.com/adsmanager/manage
2. Click Ads (beside Ad sets) > Choose the Ad you want to view
3. Hover over the ad and click 'Edit' (in between 'View Charts' and
   'Duplicate')
4. Click the 3 dots beside your ads title > More option > Manage
   Facebook Comments and you will be redirected to the page post
5. To get the exact Facebook link to the post, just remove `business.` from the URL.
   **<sub>For example, this URL:</sub>**
   `https://business.facebook.com/FBPage/posts/pfbid021mC4WqZml?dco_ad_id=6339313531020`
   <sub>**would become this one:**</sub>
   `https://facebook.com/FBPage/posts/pfbid021mC4WqZml?dco_ad_id=6339313531020`

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I was referring to the ads in the FB ad library that are not running by my ads manager account